# Not able to get {!recordId} in custom lightning component inside napili

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-apps

I need to have a custom view for Account details. So I created one component which implements both interfaces `hasrecordid` and `pageforalltypes`.

I created one variable `x` in my `controller.js` so that I could store  the `recordid` at run time and pass it to my `@AuraEnabled` apex class for further processing. For testing purposes I hard coded `x` with some Account Id and everything worked as expected when I ran it in one of my test app.

```
<aura:App>
    <c:comp/>
</aura:App>
```

---

Before moving this working component to my community I cleared `x` and made it equal to `cmp.get("v.recordid");`:

```
x=cmp.get("v.recordid");
```

I didn't define any attribute as `recordid` in `cmp` as I believed it would take the same from URL at run time.

I added the above component in the Account detail page using community builder. Then I opened one of the Account records however this time no Account related data came up.

I added `console.log` and it showed `undefined`. I added `{!recordId}` in the `component(cmp)` however nothing showed up on page load (blank).

So is there anyway I could get  this accountid at run time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your code in the post is *exactly* as you tried it, your problem may have been case sensitivity. The correct value is `recordId`, not `recordid`.

---

I have confirmed that this does work. I've written up a brief demonstration that shows how it works.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="output" type="String" />
    <div>
        {!v.output}
    </div>
    <ui:button label="Reveal" press="{!c.reveal}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    reveal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.output", component.get("v.recordId"));
    }
})
```

---

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell what you've done differently, but this does work in my community, which I tested:

[image: Demo Napili Community Record]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Ltngtabset>
  <ltngtab>
     <c:comp1/>
  </ltngtab>
  <ltngtab>
     <c:comp2/>
  </ltngtab>
</ltngtabset>
```

comp1 and com`p2 inside lightning tabsets were not taking the recordid.
Then i tested after removing tabset component and  having just individual components (comp1 and comp2)

```
<c:comp1/>
<c:comp2/>
```

in my aura component and it used the recordid.

So I Copied the entire code inside comp1 and comp2 and pasted it inside the ltngtabs and this time everything processed successfully.

`<ltngtabset>
  <ltngtab>
   all the code earlier in comp1
  </ltngtab>
  <ltngtab>
   all the code  earlier in comp2
  </ltngtab>
</ltngtabset>`

Though this worked I do not know the reasons for the same.

@sfdcfox thanks a lot for looking into this